# Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame df_forecast, contains consumption data by date. Some dates are missing. So I thought to create another data frame considering the start date & end date of df_forecast & fill it with consecutive date then do left join with df_forecast & consider the last date value for the missing dates. So I wrote following code

```
startDate=min(df_forecast$Date1)
endDate=max(df_forecast$Date1)
dateSeq=seq(as.Date(startDate), as.Date(endDate), by="days")
df_date=data.frame(dateSeq)
```

But while I'm trying to merge df_date with  df_forecast using below code

```
merge(df_date,df_forecast,by.x=dateSeq,by.y=Date1,all.x=True)
```

I'm getting error message

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must  match numbers of columns
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns
```

Both the variables in merge by are Date data type.
Can you suggest me how to solve this issue or any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

That was my first attempt at the same problem, but I found the "complete" function in tidyverse that does what you want (blog description by Kan Nishida here: https://blog.exploratory.io/populating-missing-dates-with-complete-and-fill-functions-in-r-and-exploratory-79f2a321e6b5). Here's the code to set up a replicable example and demo the function.

```
# Setting up replicable example
start_date <- Sys.Date()
end_date <- start_date + 24
date_vec <- seq.Date(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = "day")
set.seed(101)
other_data <- sample(1:25, 25)
data1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(date_vec, other_data))
data1$date_vec <- as.Date(data1$date_vec, origin = "1970-01-01")
set.seed(101)
n <- 5
# Remove 5 random rows
to_remove <- sample(data1$date_vec, n)
data_incomplete <- data1[!data1$date_vec %in% to_remove, ]
# Check it
data_incomplete
# Add rows back, other_data will be NA
data_incomplete %>% 
  mutate(date_vec = as.Date(date_vec)) %>% 
  complete(date_vec = seq.Date(from = min(date_vec), to = max(date_vec), by = "day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the columns as strings. For merge, if you add the column itself, it interprets it as an array of column names.

> Columns to merge on can be specified by name, number or by a logical vector: the name "row.names" or the number 0 specifies the row names. If specified by name it must correspond uniquely to a named column in the input.

```
merge(df_date,df_forecast,by.x='dateSeq',by.y='Date1',all.x=True)
```

R tends to be very inconsistent in this regard, so always debug by trying a coupled different ways of referencing the column.